# kafka-consumer-group describe results in consumer-group does not exist

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx, lag

I have been trying to run the following scripts programmatically in java and for the most part they work but for some this error keeps showing up:
"the consumer-group xyz does not exist". Could someone explain why this error is occurring especially if the consumer-group appears in the --list script.

```
 kafka/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --zookeeper 
 192.xxx.x.xxx:2181 --describe -group TEST_CONSUMER
```

Returns the error:

```
Error: The consumer group 'TEST_CONSUMER' does not exist.
```

But this script will list the consumer group as active:

```
kafka/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --zookeeper 192.xxx.x.xxx:2181 --list
```

So why does it if listed, then return an error stating it does not exist? Also related to consumer-groups -- I run this script to get lag info as I was told it is not possible to get this via jmx metrics in kafka 1.0 unless I connect to each consumer server or something. Could someone verify this?

Thanks

Comment: It's not specific to Kafka 1.0, but yes, the lag is only available from consumer client JMX, but you could look at tools like Burrow or Remora https://github.com/zalando-incubator/remora

Answer (score 2):

Use `bootstrap-server` not `zookeeper` [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_consumer_lag)

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group my-group
```

**Note: This will only show information about consumers that use the Java consumer API (non-ZooKeeper-based consumers).**

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried that using the server ip and the same response; changed it to localhost and got the following: "connection to node-1 could not be established"; "execution of consumer group command failed due to timeout"

Comment: Use the same hostname/ip that's being used in the `listeners` value in your server.properties file.

Comment: @Bitswazsky - thanks for suggestion. Checked the properties file and it had listeners pointing to hostname; tried that and still same error "Consumer-group does not exist". Additional info; this is a cluster of 3 servers and I tried it on all 3

Comment: Can you update the output of --list of consumer groups, and also check once again these consumers are active or not,

Comment: @Deadpool - sorry to have dragged this out. What I did was check the kafka manager tool api that we have running and it showed the consumer groups with the relevant topic but I then tried running the command above using --bootstrap-server (using localhost, ip & even hostname as listed in server properties) WARN Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
Error: Executing consumer group command failed due to Request METADATA failed on brokers List(localhost:9020 (id: -1 rack: null))

Answer (score 0):

First list the groups in cluster:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server $IP_Address:9092 --list
```

then describe the group you need:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server $IP_Address:9092 --group $GROUPID --describe
```

In case of this not working, I guess you are describing a group which is in ZK(akka old consumer), that's the old kafkaconsumer which stored in ZK. Which version of your kafka consumer client?

Comment: How to describe consumer group in old zookeeper version ?